# MVC 4, HTML input tag throwing "unterminated string constant"

Tags: html, razor, syntax-error

Hi I get this error whenever i try to create a button in html.
Error: "Unterminated string constant"
Here's the code:

```
<input id="topImageNavigationPreviousButton" type="button" value="Previous" class="inline" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { id = (id + (startIndex - endIndex) + 1) })'"/>
```

I'm using MVC 4 Razor.
Please tell me if you want me to post more of my code :)

(PS: can someone tell me how i can linebreak that code? Tried `<br/>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unterminated string constant is beacause of missing a closing quotation mark.pretty sure you have made some mistake in the syntax.

```
onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { id = (id + (startIndex - endIndex) + 1) })'"
```

Comment: nope, didn't work, and the bracket is there after (startIndex -endIndex) + 1 :(

Comment: wats the third parameter `new{ id = (id + (startIndex - endIndex) + 1)` for?

Comment: it's for getting the next image index

Comment: why you have added the `new` keyword?use `id = (id + (startIndex - endIndex) + 1` as third parameter.it should work properly.

Comment: I've switched over to mvc html helpers, but thanks for solving it :)